# Merge polyline feature at vertex intersection based on segment count

Tags: qgis, line, merge, intersection, splitting

[image: Sample network with desired before and after]

I have a Polyline layer in QGIS which is split into multiple segments using the explode lines tool (the black lines in the image). There are nodes created from the 'extract vertices' tool (the red circles in the image). I want to merge the segments but keep 3-way or greater intersections split. Dead ends can be ignored but must be kept.

When splitting the features I could not find a way to split exclusively at vertex intersections of 3 or more. I then decided to explode the line and try merging intersections with less than 3 segments, but I'm stuck again. Ideally this method can be automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to answer your *"When splitting the features I could not find a way to split exclusively at vertex intersections of 3 or more."* part.

This requires GRASS tool, so please start from opening **QGIS Desktop 3.XX with GRASS 7.XX**, not the usual *QGIS Desktop*.

[image]

Then;

1. Start **v.clean** tool ( in the `Processing Toolbox > GRASS > Vector`).
2. Click on a small ellipsis (three dots) button of `Cleaning tool`
3. Select **bpol** option.

[image]

In the `Advance parameters` option, you would better to:

- Set region extent (by calculating from your line layer)
- Set `v.in.ogr snap tolerance` to be small enough.

[image]

It will return a new `Cleaned` layer, on which you can pick each branch of split segments.

Comment: Thank you! This was incredibly helpful